# Radially Power Spectrum Analysis

Tags: matlab, fft, analysis, spectrum

First - I need to plot this radially averaged spectrum 1-D, against the wavenumber |k|. But early I calculate the |k| using two matrix, so I have a matrix that represent |k|. So I have to radial average this matrix too?

Second - If I remove a mean value from my data before using the FFT2 function, I expected to see only a difference in the amplitude of the values, but actually I am noting a difference in the shape of the radially averaged spectrum.

I am trying to use this to analyse magnetic field data.
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: You might want to post this in the physics (or math?) stackexchange site. I am not exactly sure about the first point, but a little more info might help, for instance is |k| not *only* a function of the radius?

Comment: A more general question is: what kind of symmetry are you expecting (or observe) in your image? Is the operation that gives you |k| generating a matrix with that same symmetry?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for your second question follows from the additive property of the FFT:

```
FFT(c) = FFT(a+b) = FFT(a) + FFT(b)
```

If `b` is an offset - namely the mean value - which you remove from signal `c`, then the spectrum of `c-b` will equal your original spectrum minus the spectrum of a constant, `b`, but the FFT of a constant results in sinc wiggles! So by removing the mean value of the signal you are removing a sinc glitch at zero frequency.